# Connecting to ubuntu instance in amazon ec2 without java

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

How can I connect to an ubuntu instance in amazon ec2 from my ubuntu pc without using java?

Comment: I can't find any way to connect without using java.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect over ssh using an ssh key without using their web based java ssh program.  Read the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html) about halfway down the page.

Comment: I want to connect without java.

Comment: This wouldn't use java, you can use the ssh terminal program.